# sending binary file over socket

Tags: c, sockets

I have been trying to send(using send or write functions) 40 byte of (since the requirement is it should work for any length of stream)binary file over socket. But the couldn't send more than 8byte. I tried with loop also.

what could be possible problem.

Here under is part of the code

```
    char buf;
    char *sbuf;
    FILE *fin;
    fin = fopen(file.dat, "rb");      

   while( fread(&buf, sizeof(char), 1, fin) > 0 && (fin != NULL))
   counter++;
   fseek( fin, 0 , SEEK_SET ); 
   sbuf = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(counter + 1));
   fread(sbuf, 1, counter, fin);

   // I tried both of this methods 

    int x;

  x = write(s, sbuf, sizeof(sbuf));

 printf("sent data size is %d\n", x); //prints 8bytes only while file.dat is of size    40bytes

 // the other method 

  int total = 0;
  int *len;
  int bytesleft = *len;

   while(total < *len) {
    x = write(s, sbuf+total, bytesleft);
    if (x == -1) { break; }
    total += x;
    bytesleft -= x;
   }

  printf("sent data size is %d\n", x); //also prints 8bytes only while file.dat is of size 40bytes
```

Comment: sizeof(64-bit pointer).  Guess - haven't actually looked at the code.

Comment: Aren't you trying to read the file twice without reopening or seek?

Comment: I used fseek actually, eventhough i didnt included it here...fseek( fin, 0 , SEEK_SET );

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems with your code. The first is that you need to check the file pointer `fin` *before* you try to do anything with it. It also wont be set to `NULL` automatically, so if the file is opened properly the condition `fin != NULL` will always be true in the loop.

Another problem is that you first read all data, and then you try to read more data which will fail. You use [`fseek`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) and [`ftell`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell) to get the file size very easily. Then use [`rewind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind) to go back to the beginning of the file.

When you have the size of the file you allocate memory for it, and read into that buffer. And don't use `sizeof` on a pointer, it will return the size of the pointer and not what it points to.

After you've read the file, you have to send it. You might need to send it in a loop until all data has been sent.

Comment: i checked (fin != NULL) , and its ok, I also checked/used fseek. but still the problem is there.

Comment: @user2677682 Did you read the note about using `sizeof` on a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

This code invokes undefined behavior:

```
  int *len;
  int bytesleft = *len;

   while(total < *len) { ... }
```

You have never initialized `len`. Anything can happen.

Also, you can't `fread()` after reaching end of file. You want to return to the beginning of the file before reading again. I suggest using `rewind()`

Comment: If the second is not working why is the first not working.  i have used fseek to return to the beginning eventhough i didnt included it here.